# How to retrieve Word/PDF document from Oracle table stored as BLOB in ODP.NET

Tags: c#, oracle, blob, odp.net

I am having issues retrieving a stored BLOB document (Word document stored as Bytes) and opening the original copy of that document in Microsoft Word. I select the blob column through an Oracle query by using the ID number of the data row listed in my DataGridView. My code I have so far to read the BLOB file is:

private void btnOpenCV_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
    { 

        string fileName = Path.GetTempFileName() + ".docx";
        int id = 0;

        OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(oradb);
        con.Open();
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;

        try
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewCell selectedCell in dgvSearchJob.SelectedCells)
            {
                if (selectedCell.Selected)
                    id = Convert.ToInt32(dgvSearchJob.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value);

                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT CandidateCV FROM Candidate WHERE CandidateID like '" + id + "'";
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                    using(OracleDataReader oradr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (oradr.Read())
                        {
                            int size = 1024 * 1024;
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
                            int readBytes = 0;
                            int index = 0;

                            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                            {
                                while ((readBytes = (int)oradr.GetBytes(0, index, buffer, 0, size)) >0)
                                {
                                    fs.Write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
                                    index += readBytes;
                                }
                            }                               
                        }                            
                        oradr.Close();
                    }                                                
            }

            Process prc = new Process();
            prc.StartInfo.FileName = fileName;
            prc.Start();
        }
        catch (ArgumentException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
        catch (OracleException ex1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex1.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex2)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex2.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            cmd.Dispose();
            con.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

This execution returns an exception "The system cannot find the file specified" and I am not sure why. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I assume you have debugged through it and checked the value for "filename" and then verified it exists in the filesystem and can be opened by Word?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I haven't done any form of debugging so I don't actually know if the BLOB column is returned and worked with. How would I go about finding this information out?

Comment: Forget about the database for now. Just use your debugger to look at the value for filename (some temp file). Then go to the file system and try to open that file after it gets created. The error suggests that the file isn't even being created (even with zero data)

Comment: Okay I've looked at the value of "filename" and it shows a path in the c drive: "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp3F27.tmp.docx". The file created is a tmp file. However, this tmp file cannot be found if I manually look inside my C drive.